# Trello "PUT" API Access performission requirement

Tags: trello

I like to understand what is the access permission of trello API "PUT /1/boards/[board_id]".

In document, its Required permissions: read, but this is a PUT request to Trello. Why it only has the read permission while the PUT may need to change the information on server according to HTTP protocol ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice some of the routes (like [PUT /1/boards/[board_id]/myPrefs/emailPosition](https://trello.com/docs/api/board/index.html#put-1-boards-board-id-myprefs-emailposition)) have read permission despite causing writes - because that read doesn't affect the state of the board, but rather affects how the current member views the board.

The "mass PUT" route uses the lowest-common-denominator permission so that you can use it to set anything you could set with a scoped PUT.  It will *also* check the permissions for each of the individual fields you are trying to set, and fail if you don't meet any of them.